# How to set up PostgreSQL for Play 2.0?

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework-2.0

I'd like to configure PostgreSQL for my Play app, but am getting the following error:

```
! Internal server error, for request [GET /] ->

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300000] milliseconds    at
akka.dispatch.DefaultPromise.ready(Future.scala:834)
~[akka-actor.jar:2.0]   at
akka.dispatch.DefaultPromise.result(Future.scala:838)
~[akka-actor.jar:2.0]   at akka.dispatch.Await$.result(Future.scala:74)
~[akka-actor.jar:2.0]   at
play.core.ReloadableApplication.get(ApplicationProvider.scala:108)
~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]   at
play.core.server.Server$class.sendHandler$1(Server.scala:59)
[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]    at
play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:89)
[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0] [error] application - 

! @6a64i2p5o - Internal server error, for request [GET /] ->

play.api.PlayException: Not initialized [?]     at
play.api.PlayException$.apply(Exceptions.scala:122)
~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]   at
play.core.ReloadableApplication.<init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:94)
~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]   at
play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(NettyServer.scala:165)
~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]   at
play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(NettyServer.scala:164)
~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]   at
play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:17)
~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]   at
play.core.server.NettyServer$.mainDev(NettyServer.scala:163)
~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
```

I use the following configuration files:

**application.conf**

```
db.default.url="postgres://play:play@localhost:9000/Play_Playground_DB"
db.default.user=play
db.default.password=play
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
```

**project/Build.scala**

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4"
)
```

I set up `Play_Playground_DB` and can access it via terminal and the command `psql Play_Playground_DB`.

What could be the root cause of the issue?

Comment: That URL is not anything PostgreSQL would recognize; presumably the framework is taking that apart and picking out the pieces needed?  Also, I recommend that you read this section and update your driver jar: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html#current

Comment: Thanks! Updated it to the current version.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Most probably this is the problem:

```
db.default.url="postgres://play:play@localhost:9000/Play_Playground_DB"
```

The [play doku](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaDatabase) says, "db.default.url" is a plain JDBC-URL. There are two problems with your value:

- It is not in a format recognized by PostgreSQL. Look [here](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html) for allowed formats.
- With `...default...` you redefine the default datasource. By default this calls for trouble unless you do some more steps.

A valid PostgreSQL URL might look like this in your case:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9000/Play_Playground_DB
```

**But:_** Are sure your database is running on port 9000? You say `psql Play_Playground_DB` works for you. Therefore I think your port should be the default port 5432. Then this URL is the right one:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost/Play_Playground_DB
```

Comment: Thanks, the last URL you postet is the solution. Works now! Just wondering why it is described here differently: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/SettingsJDBC

Comment: I used this config: db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/Play_Playground_DB"

Comment: @TomTom: Regarding the github link: This is about "BoneCP", a connection pool which is wedged between the DB and the application/framework. Using a connection pool often requires non-standard URLs.

Comment: I am using Play 2.0.4 and got it to work without adding jdbc: to the URL. However, you are likely to be running your PostGres on the default port (5432), especially as 9000 is the default HTTP port Play uses.

Comment: For anyone having the same issue, this is the correct answer, however I had to execute `reload` from the Play! console because modifying Build.scala won't take effect unless you exit the console, or execute `reload`, then execute `dependencies`.

Answer (score 5):

On my OSX, I've installed PostgreSQL from homebrew and current version is 9.3.4

The connection strings described above do not work for me because they are using *postresql* database name. My connections are established if and only if I specify like:

```
db.default.url="postgres://user:password@localhost/MyDbName"
```

Notice that it is *postgres* instead of *postgresql*.

Comment: This solved the problem I was having.  I'm using Postgres 9.2.3 and Play 2.3.0