# Play! framework - Cannot connect to database

Tags: java, database, postgresql, ubuntu, playframework-2.0

this is the error I get when I'm trying to connect to my local postgresql db:

> Cannot connect to database [default]

this is the database configuration. **I'm convinced that there is not typo (fat finger error)**:

```
db.default.url="postgres://localhost:5432/myproject/"
db.default.user="postgres"
db.default.pass="mypassword"
db.default.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
db.default.initSQL="SELECT 1"
```

where is the problem? **with pgAdmin I can connect easily**
p.s.
I'm using ubuntu. I've noticed that in order to change to postgres user
**I must use "su"**, otherwise it fails changing the current user.
is that has something to do with play! failure to connect my db?

thanks

Comment: Did you add the Postgres JDBC driver as a Play dependency ?

Comment: yes I did:
val appDependencies = Seq(
      "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4"
    )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be **two** things wrong or at least dubious in your setup.

First: The `postgres:...` URL syntax is not a plain JDBC URL. This format is not understood by the PostgreSQL JDBC driver. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10284328/947357) to a similar problem.

Second: You are trying to use the PostgreSQL superuser account for Play. The superuser account should be used **only** for administrative work, but not "normal" work. *Especially* not for work which includes public access to the DB via some webfrontend. Any SQL-Injection attack gives the attacker the golden key to your database - including the nuke to wreck your complete DB cluster at once or install any backdoor into you DB server.

So I recommand, that you create a new user which you configure in your Play! settings.

That said: The default password for the `postgres` user is *not* set on Ubuntu. This setup allows login to the *DB user* only from the same *OS user*. How you can fix this is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7696398/947357).

*If these two tips don't help:* The error you quoted is very vague. There *must* be more detailed error logs *somewhere*. Please find them and attach them to your question with the "edit" button.

Comment: but I did set a password for the user postgres as I mentioned.
I can even login with pgAdmin.
as for the syntax. that's what the play! framework docs says.

Comment: @socksocket: Did you actuall try the first part?

Comment: oh missed it. I'll try in this very moment

Comment: @socksocket what exactly did your problem end up being and how did you fix it? I am seeing the same error in my Play 2.0 app on Heroku.

Comment: @JayTaylor: I assume, he used the link in the "First..." part.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer directly to your question, but I had the same error message and came here via Google. Using Scala Play 2.3, I had

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/noob_development"
db.default.logStatements=true
```

which needed to be

```
db.default.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/noob_development"
db.default.logStatements=true
```

I accidentally left the quotes around the driver name out. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

here is my conf, it works:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/dbname"
db.default.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
```

just add the `jdbc:` before `postgresql` in `db.default.url`.