# Scala Play! Postgres connection fails

Tags: postgresql, scala, jdbc, playframework, sbt

I have the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782212/play-framework-cannot-connect-to-database/) problem, bur I have also specified connection properties with quotes, jdbs:postgresQL etc

```
db.default.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://my_user:my_pass@my.host:5432/postdb"
db.default.user=my_user    
db.default.password="my_pass"
```

Password,driver with or without quotes, same error

```
Configuration error
Cannot connect to database [default]
```

There many question like this, but it was solved when defining "postgresql" instead "postgres" or quoting didn't help

but I can connect to database with psql -h my.host -U my_user postdb 
(Ubuntu)

Also in [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/SettingsJDBC) we see url db.default.url=postgres://localhost:root@secret/myDatabase where another order for username, pass etc, but it also doesn't work

I have `libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.2-1003-jdbc4"` in build.sbt

Can someone suggest what the problem is? thanks
P.S. I am new in scala, any help would be useful

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what makes the difference, but here's what's working for me with the same library version (`9.2-1003-jdbc4`):

`db.default.url="postgres://username:pwd@localhost:5432/dbname"`

Comment: Thank You, but I tried to connect with url like this at the beginning. Maybe I missed some import or something else at other files? But compilatin was successful