# Cannot connect to database [default]

Tags: java, postgresql, rest, playframework

I have just started working on play framework. I am trying to build rest api, and is using postgresql for my db connection. It is my first time using both play and postgre. I have made a db connection inside build.sbt. But while running the app I am getting the following issue,

```
play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:94) ~[play_2.11-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:743) ~[play_2.11-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:247) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:238) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:274) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "localhost:5432/sampledb" does not exist
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.readStartupMessages(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:572) ~[postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:177) ~[postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64) ~[postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136) ~[postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29) ~[postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar:na]
```

I have postgre installed in my local in port 5432, my db configuration in application.conf looks like -

```
 db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
 db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql:localhost:5432/sampledb"
 db.default.user=postgres
 db.default.password="test"
```

Any help will be highly appreciated, also I will be really grateful, if link to any good tutorial on play with java can be provided. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a database called `sampledb`? And don't write tags into your question topic.

Comment: yes sampledb is there.

Comment: And that user has access to that database (ie you can connect using pgAdmin)? Also user should be quoted (`"postgres"`)

Comment: yes, I just tried using 

>> db.default.url="postgres://user:password@localhost/MyDbName"

as the url format. and it picked it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the url string in the format and it picked it up -

> db.default.url="postgres://user:password@localhost/MyDbName"

Taken from- [How to set up PostgreSQL for Play 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282402/configure-postgresql-for-play-framework-2-0/10284328#10284328)